# Prevent Journald writing to /var/log

Tags: systemd-journald

Is it possible to configure **journald** *not* to write entries to **/var/log/messages** on **Centos**?

I tried by setting `ForwardToSyslog=no` in **/etc/systemd/journald.conf**:

- CentOS Linux release 7.3
- systemd 219

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it is `rsyslogd` or `syslogd` that write to `/var/log/messages`.
Try stopping and / or disabling the respective service.

Comment: Thanks, `rsyslogd` reconfig solved it.